# marking a location on the map v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using the simple code to create a map on my site:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    scrollwheel: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.80962, -77.13143),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);
    var customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        title:"Carlos Gallupa HQ",
        icon: image
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Now I am having issue pinpointing my location using a marker. Any idea how I can do it simple and right? Thanks.

Comment: What location are you having trouble creating a marker for?

Comment: By 'my location' do you mean the location determined by the browser the user is using? Is it for desktop or mobile? The maps API documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference doesn't mention it so perhaps it's not controllable through script for privacy reasons?

Comment: Getting the location from the browser isn't a part of the google api, but it is possible. [Have a look here.](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html)

Comment: I am talking about creating/placing a marker for center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.80962, -77.13143), or circling its radius.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your marker position is not defined anywhere. Try this:

```
var customMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    // Here is the change:
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    shadow: shadow,
    title:"Carlos Gallupa HQ",
    icon: image
});
```